# Facebook scrollTo not working in iframe?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to have my iframe load up to the top of the page when the page refreshes. Basically I have an iframe, the initial page high is 1250px but the 2nd page that it sends you to is only 500px in height. The problem is when your redirected to the new page you only see white space and have to scroll up.

I have tried using the following:

```
$("#postyourwave").click(function(){
    FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);
});
```

but to no luck. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the scrolling iframe within the canvas, I have been told this is not possible. If someone knows please fill me in! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Canvas Height to 'fixed' within the application settings.

Comment: it is set to a fixed height of 1000, is it not possible to do this within an iframe?